# Incredibly odd iOS 10 site visit and logging issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, google-analytics, safari, ios10

Im not even sure how to begin to be honest.  One of my sites is a very populate education website.  We log all site visits, the ip address, referrer and other information for tracking and affiliate payouts.

On 9/14 we saw a HUGE spike in our internal numbers for direct traffic.  It's not reflected in Google Analytics, but it's in our logs.

Upon further investigation, we were able to isolate ALL of the traffic to a single user agent:

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1`

So as soon as iOS 10 came online, we saw this odd massive spike.  Logically (and according to GA) there was no reason why iOS 10 should become this massive source of traffic bringing in orders of magnitude more direct traffic.

When we dove further, we discovered something else.  If we look at the IP Address count for any day after the 14th and for traffic from the above user agent (iOS 10) we see things like this:

`ip_address    | count
-----------------+-------
73.178.228.81   |    72
104.231.85.1    |    48
73.219.188.93   |    44`

but if we look at ANY OTHER user agent, iOS 9.3.5 for example, we see normal traffic:

`ip_address    | count
-----------------+-------
68.100.68.242   |    11
141.239.187.223 |     7
70.211.8.103    |     6`

This is completely stumping us.  Does anyone have ANY IDEA why traffic from Safari in iOS 10 could produce different results than any other version before it?